# How to access elements inside rows and columns

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, grid, rows, element

I want to access all elements that are inside a grid that contains columns and rows.

I made an edit on a method i found , but it always returns null .

```
 private static FrameworkElement GetChildren(Grid grid, int row, int column)
        {
            FrameworkElement fr = null;

            foreach (FrameworkElement child in grid.Children)
            {
                if ((Grid.GetRow(child) == row) && (Grid.GetColumn(child) == column))
                {

                      fr = child;
                }
                else
                {

                      fr = null;
                }
            }

            return fr;

        }  //getchildren
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct but your algorithm is wrong.

Suppose that the grid contains two elements. The first one is the one you're searching for.

1. The `foreach` enumerates all the controls, and returns the first one. It's the right row and column, so you assign it to `fr`.
2. The `foreach` goes on and returns the second one. It's not the right row/column, so you assign `null` to `fr`.
3. The `foreach` loop has finished enumerating the elements, and returns `fr`, which is null.

Basically, your code will only work if the element is the last child of the grid.

To fix your algorithm, use the `break` instruction to exit the loop when you find the control:

```
FrameworkElement fr = null;

foreach (FrameworkElement child in grid.Children)
{
    if ((Grid.GetRow(child) == row) && (Grid.GetColumn(child) == column))
    {
          fr = child;
          break;
    }
}

return fr;
```

Alternatively, you can use Linq to make your code shorter:

```
return grid.Children
    .OfType<FrameworkElement>()
    .FirstOrDefault(child => Grid.GetRow(child) == row && Grid.GetColumn(child) == column);
```